# How do I wire a new 3-Way switch with the old existing wiring (2 black & 1 Red wire)?

Tags: wiring, switch

I connected the 2 black wires with a pigtail and attached to one side and attached the red wire to the other side, lights did not work.

[image: 3-way switch old (R) & new (L)]

Comment: The two blacks are not the same and should not be connected/pigtail together.  With three ways you take pictures and label each wire to which screw it is connected to before undoing them.  You then might be able to wire up a new switch.

Comment: You should seriously consider a bit more self education before further wiring attempts. Borrow a book from the library. Removing wires from two different terminals on "old device" and joining them when installing "new device" is virtually always going to be wrong, sometimes in a very drastic manner. Learning this stuff is possible, but you have to be willing to think, and learn, not just blindly put things together because they are the same color.... And **always** take **before** pictures with all the wires still connected.

Answer (score 2):

If wires are attached only to the brass screws on either side of the new switch, then nothing will happen.  This is the expected outcome of what you did.  The 3-pole switch is designed to alternate between those two screws and does not connect them internally.

If the old switch did not have a pigtail then adding one to the new switch is also wrong.

Most importantly, the screws on these two switches are not in the same place.  Without knowing exactly what you did or how, my only guess is that the red wire might belong on the black screw.

Answer (score 1):

The old switch has screws out of sight top and bottom, I believe. Two of those are the same color, like the brass screws on the new switch, and one of them is a different color, like the black on the new switch.

The new switch also has text labelling identifying Black Screw as common. The odd colored screw on the old switch is also common. It's how 3-way switches *(Commonwealth folk: Note - USA/Canada meaning of 3-way)* are done. Most likely the common is, for physical construction reasons, also the bottom most terminal on the old switch, so it had one of the blacks on it, apparently, if the B R B have the expected meaning.

The wire removed should go to the same terminal (function) on the new switch as the old. If you've now mixed up which black wire went where, you'll have to try both ways, since it appears that you or someone did identify the color-to-terminal marking on the old switch. The travelers (brass screws) don't really matter which one is which, as the other one connects to common whenever the switch is flipped.